# criteria for flatness of map $f:A \to A[X]/P(X)=:B$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $A$ commutative ring with $1$ and $P(X) \in A[X]$ a non constant polynomial. Can it be exactly characterized when the canonical map $f:A \to A[X]/P(X)=:B$ is

(1) flat or
(2) induces surjective map $Spec(f): Spec(B) \to Spec(A), \mathfrak{p} \mapsto \mathfrak{p} \cap A$

Note: in case when (1) and (2) hold at the same time $f$ is called faithfully flat. But in general there is no connection between (1) and (2), therefore these can be studied separately

Comment: Remark I.2.6 of Milne's "Etale Cohomology" might be of interest to you here. In particular, he claims that if $A$ is connected, then $B$ is flat over $A$ if and only if the coefficients of $P$ generate the unit ideal of $A$. It should be noted that Prop I.2.5, to which Remark I.2.6 refers, is incorrectly stated: see the errata for details.

Answer (score 2):

**Question:** "..criteria for flatness of map f:A→A[X]/P(X)=:B"

**Answer:** Assume $B:=A[x_1,..,x_n]/I$ with $I:=(f_1,..,f_k)$. If $A \rightarrow B$ is flat it follows  it follows $A \rightarrow B$ is faithfully flat iff for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq A$ it follows the ideal $\overline{I} \subseteq k[x_1,..,x_n]$ is not the unit ideal, where $k:=A/\mathfrak{m}$ and $\overline{I}$ is the "reduction of $I$ modulo $k$". This follows from a lemma in Milne, "Etale cohomology":

[Characterizing fppf-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253418/characterizing-fppf-algebras/4253793#4253793)

**Example:** In your case, if $f(x):=a_nx^n+\cdots +a_1x+a_0\in A[X]$ it follows $\overline{f(x)}:=\overline{a_n}x^n+\cdots +\overline{a_0} \in k[x]$ with $k:=A/\mathfrak{m}$, is the unit ideal iff $a_i \in \mathfrak{m}$ for $i=1,..,n$ and $a_0 \in A-\mathfrak{m}$. Hence you can read this off the coefficents of $f(x)$. If $f(x)$ is monic of degree $\geq 1$ the map is faithfully flat.

If $P(x)$ is a monic polynomial it follows $A \rightarrow B$ is integral, hence $Spec(B) \rightarrow Spec(A)$ is surjective by Atiyah-Macdonald, Thm 5.10.

Comment: so this answers the case when (2) is true, assuming (1) (flatness). Do we know something about creteria when (2) is true without flatness assumption?